# dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys inside loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

Trying to add values to dictionary using dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys , I want to add the objects using a for loop and i am not able to find the right way out , please help , Using for loop only the last values is shown other values dont appear. Looks like the values are overiding and not getting appended.

normal code without for loop

```
toListDictUnSorted = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:316], @"USD 50000", @"English", nil], @"USA",
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:194], @"USD 12000", @"Portugese", nil], @"Brazil",
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1210], @"USD 1592", @"Hindi", nil], @"India",
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1353], @"USD 6075", @"Chinese", nil], @"China",
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:143], @"USD 14037", @"Russian", nil], @"Russia",
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:59], @"USD 33115]", @"Italian", nil], @"Italy",
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:63], @"USD 38591", @"English", nil], @"Great Britain",
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:29], @"USD 25000", @"Arabic", nil], @"Saudi Arabia",
                               nil]; */
```

for loop code

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_toData count]; i++)
         {

             toListDictUnSorted = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:meters], [[_toData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"], nil], [[_toData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"] , nil];



        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an NSMutableDictionary instead of an NSDictionary

Edit:

You want this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *toListDictUnSorted = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [_toData count]; i++)
    {
        [toListDictUnSorted setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:meters], [[_toData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"], nil] forKey:[[_toData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]];
    }
```

Comment: Tried using NSMutableDictionary, but only the last value get added which is inside the for loop.

Comment: You have to change the type of the Dictionary not the Array's. 
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dict setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:316], @"USD 50000", @"English", nil] forKey:@"USA"];
The for loop should work then using "setObject:forKey:"

Comment: Then, probably you are using the same key for each iteration

Comment: i have checked all keys are different, Looks like the values are overiding and not getting appended, Is anything i can change in the existing code